# Evaluate complex mathematical expressions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have expressions similar to: 300 <= x < 400. At run time I replace x by a specific value and then I will evaluate the expression to get a true or false.

Using eval() function always returns true for the above expression, in a time it should be false.

Any idea how to evaluate such expressions?

Thanks

Comment: That's because that isn't how you evaluate ranges in javascript. You need to do 2 expressions with x. for example: `if(x >= 300 && x < 400) // In range.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, as is nearly all major programming languages, you have to treat `300 <= x < 400` as **two** expressions, not one, like this:

```
300 <= x && x < 400
```

The `&&` means "and" (you'll find `&&` in *lots* of languages).

You don't need to (and shouldn't) use `eval` at all for this, just use the expressions directly:

```
if (300 <= x && x < 400) {
    // ...
}
```

The reason`300 <= x < 400` doesn't give you the result you expect is that it works like this:

1. Evaluate `300 <= x` and get a result (`true` or `false`)
2. Substitute that result into where that subexpression was and evaluate the resulting `result < 400`

Since the result in step 1 is a boolean, `result < 400` will always be `true`, because `result` will be coerced to a number, and `true` coerces to `1` and `false` coerces to `0`.

Comment: You can also simply do `return 300 <= x && x < 400` if all you're doing is getting true/false values from the evaluation

Comment: Not sue why this answer got an immediate upvote, and the exact same answer (which has been deleted) got a downvote. Admittedly yours explains it better, but the other one wasn't wrong.

Comment: T.J. the expression I have is a string, so how could I execute it without using eval?

Comment: @Bill: Ah, that wasn't clear from the question. If it's a string, the yes, either you have to parse it (which is non-trivial) or use `eval` on it (if you trust the source of the string).

Comment: Yes, the formula is stored in the database in addition to the values. Thanks.